# Inserting values into array while searching another array in C?

Tags: c, arrays, search, for-loop

i'm a beginner in c, i have attempted to insert a value into an array as i scan another array for a value higher than a threshold, if a value is over the set threshold in the array being searched then insert a number into the other array...

```
    for (i = 0; i<lines[i][1]; i++) {
    if (lines[i][1] > 6500) {
    array[];
    }
```

so what i mean is, if there is a value in lines[i][1] higher than 6500, then insert number "1" into array[].

However, with previous attempts it just overwrites the array rather than stacks on top of previous values.. i have another for loop attempting to do the same thing while searching another array.

```
    for (i = 0; i<lines[i][0]; i++) {
    if (lines[i][0] > 6500) {
    array[];
    }
```

The ideal output would be something like: 1 for values higher than in lines[i][0] and 2 for values higher than in lines[i][1], "array[] = {1,1,1,2,2,2,2,1,1,1,};" 
and the values are inserted into the array as arrays are being scanned.

Please help... thank you

Answer (score 1):

Just start a counter to keep track of the position where you last inserted the item on the destination array. For example:

```
int destPosition=0;
for (i = 0; i<lines[i][0]; i++) {
    if (lines[i][0] > 6500) {
       array[destPosition]=1;
       destPosition++;
    }  
}
```

Comment: Thank you i will try this suggestion and get back to you :)